# Change schema of IdentityUser Tables in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating a project with Web Api 2.0 and Using Form Authentication. My problem is changing the default schema names of AspNet auto generated tables.

For example;

`dbo.AspNetUsers ---> User.AspNetUsers`

I have already tried to change them in the database with ALTER SCHEMA query and I have added this model to my project

```
public class UserAccount:IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>{
 .....
}
```

However I have got the following error;

> The entity type `UserAccount` is not part of the model for the current context

Any idea how I can resolve this issue. Or can I change the default schema from `dbo` to something else with the `Owin`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved the issue, and the you can see how did I do this

First I have executed the following query

```
ALTER SCHEMA User TRANSFER dbo.AspNetUsers
```

and also other related tables too.

In the application, I have added and edmx file with empty table set and referenced to the below IdentityDbContext

```
public partial class LicaDatabaseEntities : IdentityDbContext<UserAccount>
{
    public LicaDatabaseEntities()
        : base("LicaDatabaseEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("User");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

in the Startup

```
UserManagerFactory =
            () => new UserManager<UserAccount>(new UserStore<UserAccount>(new LicaDatabaseEntities()));
```

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the latest version of OWIN and EF as of now (2015-02-26).
I changed a few things and it's using "Membership" SQL Schema instead of "dbo"

0- I changed the connectionString's name:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MembershipConnection" connectionString="Server=.;Integrated Security=True;Database=AWU" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

1-1- I changed `IdentityModels.cs` like this:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MembershipConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }
```

1-2- I added this override method to `IdentityModels.cs`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Membership");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

2- I changed the way EF works with SQL since I have "MS-SQL 2014" installed on my machine

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="MembrshipConnection"/>
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

**I believe the most important part is `1-2` which tells the EF to use a default Schema when creating SQL tables. I didn't touch OWIN's Startup.cs**